# _usr_bin_gnome-shell.120.crash every boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, gnome-shell, crash

Recently, every time I boot my, otherwise stable, 18.04 system (installed on SSD), I get the error pop-up:

[image]

Clicking on "Report problem..." does not present any other information.

Checking the /var/crash folder there is always just one report:

```
$ ls /var/crash
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.120.crash
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or fix this issue, can anyone point me in the right direction.

**Settings > About > Graphics**: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A9
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [144d:c0d1]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr  6  2019 .
drwx------ 3 user user 4096 Feb  3 16:52 ..
```

After installing `$ sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell` and Firefox GNOME Shell Integration extension, https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ in Firefox shows only:
Ubuntu AppIndicators
Ubuntu Dock

**Update**: 2020-02-04
I am unable to reproduce this error. Possibly fixed with apt upgrade done yesterday.

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -A3 -i 2020-02-03
Start-Date: 2020-02-03  15:43:21
Commandline: apt full-upgrade
Requested-By: user (1000)
Upgrade: fdisk:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), bluez:amd64 (5.48-0ubuntu3.2, 5.48-0ubuntu3.3), uuid-runtime:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), libfdisk1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), bluez-cups:amd64 (5.48-0ubuntu3.2, 5.48-0ubuntu3.3), libmount1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), sudo:amd64 (1.8.21p2-3ubuntu1.1, 1.8.21p2-3ubuntu1.2), util-linux:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), mount:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), libblkid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), libuuid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), libsmartcols1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), rfkill:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), bsdutils:amd64 (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4, 1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.5), bluez-obexd:amd64 (5.48-0ubuntu3.2, 5.48-0ubuntu3.3), libbluetooth3:amd64 (5.48-0ubuntu3.2, 5.48-0ubuntu3.3)
End-Date: 2020-02-03  15:43:31
```

**Update**: 2020-02-06
I just got another similar crash after signing in from laptop close lid sleep, but this time two crash reports, one when I closed the lid (I guess, from the time) and one when I signed back in:

```
$ ls -al /var/crash
total 20864
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie     4096 Feb  6 12:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root         4096 Apr 26  2018 ..
-rw-r-----  1 gdm  whoopsie 21302671 Feb  6 11:40 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.120.crash
-rw-r-----  1 gdm  whoopsie    50961 Feb  6 12:43 _usr_bin_Xwayland.120.crash

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        5.0G        373M        780M        2.3G        1.7G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G

$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 10

$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Update 2**: 2020-02-06
Chat suggestion:
Resize swapfile to 8GiB
Adjust swappiness back to default (60)
That done, reporting back with news positive/negetive in the next few days.

Comment: Please provide more details: video adapter and driver used, Xorg or Wayland, physical hardware or virtual machine (of which vendor).

Comment: The output of  `inxi -G`  would be useful.

Comment: I think that more video details are not needed. And also please try to switch to GNOME on Xorg session on login via GDM. Does GNOME Shell really crash on each login?

Comment: You probably have a bad GNOME Shell extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: What do you see at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/?

Comment: @heynnema, added 2 crash reports I just got after a lid close sleep and a re-sign in. This time gnome-shall and Xwayland.

Comment: Oh, are you running Wayland? At the login screen, click your username, then the cogwheel icon, and please choose a different DE and see if the crashes continue.

Comment: @heynnema, $ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE, still comes back with x11, no change there. I will try Wayland at sign-in and re-sign-in for the next few days and report back.
FYI, I have subsequently closed lid for laptop sleep, then woken up and re-signed-in without any crash report. The only difference I can deduce is 1st time, when both gnome-shell & Xwayland crashes were reported my system was on high memory usage, and even some swapfile was being utilised (MiBs not GiBs available though), whereas the 2nd time, I had closed most tabs, and swap was clean - coincidence?

Comment: We don't want to run Wayland. Regarding RAM/swap... show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Don't use Wayland. /swapfile=8G, vm.swappiness=60 to start, maybe =80 later

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments and chat...

- We assured that we were not running Wayland
- Confirmed that there were no bad GNOME Shell extensions
- We enlarged /swapfile from 2G to 8G
- We changed vm.swappiness=10 to vm.swappiness=60

And so far it's running good.