# _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash every boot

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I am experiencing this crash (_usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash) on every boot on an almost new and clean install of ubuntu 18.04.

I tried the suggested solution to this question: [_usr_bin_gnome-shell.120.crash every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207716/usr-bin-gnome-shell-120-crash-every-boot)
But it didn't work for me.

Update:
I tried turning off all extensions via https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. I even tried deleting them all. I also restarted gnome shell. But the crash-report returns every time I boot even though there's none extensions installed (except ubuntu dock and ubuntu app indicators, and they are not activated).

Update 28th of march:
Outpu from `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
    totalt 12
    drwxrwxr-x 3 [username] 4096 mar 24 20:53 .
    drwx------ 3 [username] 4096 mar 28 08:48 ..
    drwxrwxr-x 4 [username] 4096 mar 24 20:53 hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca
```

Output from `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
    totalt 16
    drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 mar 23 20:56 .
    drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 feb  3 19:24 ..
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 feb  3 19:24 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 feb  3 19:24 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Update 2nd of April:
output from `ls -al /var/crash`

```
    totalt 21308
    drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie     4096 apr  1 11:46 .
    drwxr-xr-x 14 root root         4096 feb  3 19:30 ..
    -rw-r-----  1 gdm  whoopsie 21032498 mar 31 20:26 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash
    -rw-r-----  1 gdm  whoopsie   776351 apr  1 12:02 _usr_bin_Xwayland.121.crash
```

Update April 8th:
I am logged in as Ubuntu, not Ubuntu Wayland.

Here is the output from `grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

```
    WaylandEnable=false
```

I have the numix theme and icons installed. Installation inspiration from here: https://itsfoss.com/install-numix-ubuntu/

Comment: Probably a GNOME Shell extension problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I posted what you suggested.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Did you remember to restart GNOME Shell? Show me `ls -al /var/crash` and we'll fix that. Also, please repeat the previous `ls` commands.

Comment: @heynnema I made an update :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy !@#$% Batman! You've got way TOO many GNOME Shell extensions, AND they're installed in the wrong place, AND, one or more of them is causing your GNOME Shell crashes.

When/if you get a System Problem window for GNOME Shell, make sure to click `Do not send report`, or `Send report`. Do not just click the window close "X". For this problem, click `Do not send a report`.

All of the extensions installed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` are in the wrong place. The only extensions that should be there are `ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com` and `ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com`. Did you manually install the others there?

To troubleshoot which one, or more, is causing your problem, go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and **TURN OFF ALL extensions**. Restart the GNOME Shell with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, or just reboot the computer. **Really**. See if your system becomes more stable. It should.

Then later, **enable ONE EXTENSION AT A TIME**, and if problem returns, you found a bad extension. Remember that you can, and probably do, have more than one extension causing your problem.

If you have some experience, you can open the `terminal` application, and type `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog* | more` and you might be able to identify which specific extensions are causing problems.

Lastly, you'll want to remove all **unnecessary** extensions, and eventually move the remaining extensions (except for `ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com` and `ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com`) into the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` folder.

**Update #1:**

To remove the troublesome .crash files... (only do this one time...)

In `terminal`, type:

`sudo rm -i /var/crash/*.crash`

Remember, when you get a crash report window, you must click either `Send Report` or `Don't Send Report` to properly handle the crash so it won't appear again and again. Don't just close the window by clicking the `x`.

**Update #2:**

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

#WaylandEnable=false

to:

WaylandEnable=false

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks for all your help - it is very much appreciated!

Comment: @rune_b Status please...

Comment: I will of course make sure to accept your answer, but so far the crash keeps recurring, so the problem is not solved for me. Should I click accept in spite of this? Even though your answer has not solved the problem for me, your answer has been helpful in the sense that I have tidied up a bit.

Comment: @rune_b No, you shouldn't accept my answer until we solve the problem. Did you do Update #1 in my answer? Are `/var/crash/*.crash` files re-appearing? Show me `ls -al /var/crash` again. Do Update #2 in my answer. Keep me in the loop.

Comment: Yes, I did update # 1, but without any effect - both crash-files reappears. Update # 2 didn't work either. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @rune_b  Are you logging in as "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu with Wayland"? Did you reboot after doing Update #2? Please recheck your edits. You only have 3 GNOME Shell extensions installed, correct? Please disable `hidetopbar` and restart GNOME Shell.

Comment: @rune_b Show me `grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

Comment: @rune_b Do you have any custom themes or icon packs installed?

Comment: I updated - sorry it took me a while.

Comment: @rune_b Thanks for the update. In `terminal` do `sudo rm -i /var/crash/*.crash`. Also, temporarily disable the numix theme and icons, and use the standard theme and fonts. Make sure the .crash files have been deleted. Then reboot.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed answer! Finally it worked - I followed your suggestion once more, and then it somehow worked. I didn't disable the numix theme and icons. I've had the hide top bar-extension turned off for a while now, but now I've tried to reactivate it in order to see what happens. Thanks again for your help!